# how to bind 2 events with JQuery's .on method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which is working great on already created divs

```
$('.MyDivs').click(function(){
      $('#OtherDiv').css('display','block');
}).mouseleave(function(){
      $('#OtherDiv').css({ display: 'none' });
});
```

but does not work on dynamically created new Divs. I know there is a **.on** method of Jquery for dynamically created divs but do not know how to bind 2 events with it. I tried something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.MyDivs', function()
{
     $('#OtherDiv').css('display','block');
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $('#OtherDiv').css({ display: 'none' });
});
```

I also tried this

```
$(document).on('click', '.MyDivs', function()
{
     $('#OtherDiv').css('display','block');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.MyDivs', function()
{
     $('#OtherDiv').css({ display: 'none' });
});
```

but does not work. How can I bind click and mouseleave methods with .on?

***My Problem***

I just want to show **Otherdiv** on click of any div which has **.MyDivs** class and hide **Otherdiv** when mouse leaves currently **.MyDivs** div

Comment: How does that last one NOT work?

Comment: I don't know why last one is not working

Comment: It is the same as the selected answer, just a different format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this. This should work.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    },
    click: function() {
        // Handle click...
    }
}, ".MyDivs");
```

Comment: No this behaves just like my above code and remvoes Otherdiv immediately even the mouse is still inside .MyDivs div

Comment: you said your problem is "on" method. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I just want to show **Otherdiv** on click of any div which has **.MyDivs** class and hide **Otherdiv** when mouse leaves currently **.MyDivs** div

Comment: Check this fiddle it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/6mhrw/ change it to your non working code, I will check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `on` for each chain. This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.MyDivs', function() {
    $('#OtherDiv').css('display','block');
}).on('mouseleave', '.MyDivs', function() {
    $('#OtherDiv').css('display','none'});
});
```

Or you can bind both events and look for the `event.type`, then toggle the div depending on the result:

```
$(document).on('click mouseleave', '.MyDivs', function(e) {
    $('#OtherDiv').toggle( e.type == 'click' );
});
```

Comment: No this behaves just like my above code and remvoes Otherdiv immediately even the mouse is still inside .MyDivs div