# How to use two events in one `.on` jQuery code

Tags: jquery, events

This is the code which is work well without any problems :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    },
    click: function() {
        // Handle click...
    }
}, ".MyDivs");
```

I found this code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579250/how-to-bind-2-events-with-jquerys-on-method)

But it didn't resolve my problem, My problem is i want to do same operation and its not a short code and i want to make it shorter than what is it right now.

This is my current code :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        sameOperation();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        sameOperation();
    },
    click: function() {
        sameOperation();
    }
}, ".MyDivs");
```

And this is the code which i want but its not working :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseleave,mouseenter,click: function() {
        sameOperation();
    }
}, ".MyDivs");
```

Comment: You mean `on('mouseleave mouseenter click', '.MyDivs', function(){...})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `on()` can be a space-delimited string of the event names, instead of an object:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave mouseenter click', '.MyDivs', sameOperation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this.

```
$('.MyDivs').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(e) {
    sameOperation();
});
```

This will trigger the same function on 3 different events.

Comment: This isn't the same as the OPs original. They are using a delegated event handler

Comment: but its not gonna effect all of `.MyDivs` classes its gonna effect the only `.MyDivs` which loaded before this javascript code and its not gonna effect if we append more `.MyDivs` on the page

Comment: Well, you will have to bind the events again for newly added elements on your page.

Comment: @MayankPatel that's not true. Use a delegated event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Rory McCrossa I got your point.